# How to have exit return me to main menu(Java)

Tags: java, loops, do-while

Can someone show me how to have this code return you to main menu when 4 is pressed. I know that I have to do while loops but im not sure how to. Right now I have exit as a return so it closes the whole program but instead I want it to return to main menu and restart eventSelection.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SchedulingProgram
 {
  public static void main (String [] args)
   {
    eventSelection();
   }
  public static void eventSelection()
{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Select Scheduling Action");
System.out.print("Add and Event = 1. \nDisplay Events = 2. \nPrint Alert = 3. \nExit = 4. \nINPUT : ");
int actionSelect = sc.nextInt();

if (actionSelect >= 1 && actionSelect <= 4)
 {
 if (actionSelect == 1)
  {
   addEvent();
  }
 else if (actionSelect == 2)
  {
   displayEvent();
  }
 else if (actionSelect == 3)
  {
   printAlert();
  }
 else if (actionSelect == 4)
  {
   return;
  }
 }
else
 {
  System.out.println("Error : Choice " + actionSelect + " Does Not Exist.");
 }
}
```

Comment: So how user will exit your program?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again and again? You just asked this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806696/how-to-return-to-main-menu-when-exit-is-inputted one hour back. And the comments in the link above already suggest what you need to do. Why post this again?

Comment: @user3493289 your link point to this question

Comment: @MojtabaSafaeian - Updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an infinite loop like this, but user will have no option to completely exit your program, if you want a command to exit program, you can use `return` in that command.

```
 public static void eventSelection()
{
    while (true){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Select Scheduling Action");
        System.out.print("Add and Event = 1. \nDisplay Events = 2. \nPrint Alert = 3. \nExit = 4. \nINPUT : ");
        int actionSelect = sc.nextInt();

        if (actionSelect >= 1 && actionSelect <= 4)
        {
            if (actionSelect == 1)
            {
                addEvent();
            }
            else if (actionSelect == 2)
            {
                displayEvent();
            }
            else if (actionSelect == 3)
            {
                printAlert();
            }
            else if (actionSelect == 4)
            {
                System.out.println("Returning to selection menu");// Do nothing, next loop will be executed
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error : Choice " + actionSelect + " Does Not Exist.");
        }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Return some value from eventSelection().Check in main function what value is returned.If it is matching with your value then call again eventSelection()